# Objective C AVAudioRecorder with Dictation

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, dictation

I've been trying to make the AVAudioRecorder work with iOS dictation. What I have done so far was to start the AVAudioRecorder first then the user with press the mic button on the keyboard to start the dictation. I found out that the dictation interrupts the AVAudioRecorder and the recording stops.  Using AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, I tried to restart the recording as soon as it interrupted. It worked but the dictation does not "hear" anything.

Is there a way to record the user's voice while using dictation in iOS? (I'm also aware that unlike android, Objective C does not expose the voice data being sent to their server.)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also stuck with the same thing. Let me know if you found any workaround or solution for this..

Comment: Unfortunately no.  We are currently exploring using paid libraries.

Comment: hmm... Same here. Could not make it work..